# How to add a primary constructor to a generic class with type constraints?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Given the following minimal example:

```
interface IA
interface IB

class Foo1<T> where T : IA, T : IB {
    val x: Int
    constructor(x: Int) {
        this.x = x
    }
}

class Foo2<T>(val x: Int)

class Foo3<T> where T : IA, T : IB (val x: Int) // Error
```

`Foo3` is a syntax error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `where` clause comes after parameters. `class Foo3<T> (x: Int) where T : IA, T : IB`

Comment: @Vindicar Oh, yes. You are totally right. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# `where` clause comes after parameters.

```
class Foo3<T> (x: Int) where T : IA, T : IB
```

Comment: Same in Kotlin. ;)